# Marking build as unstable if tests are skipped

Tags: automated-testing, jenkins

I use tests checking their preconditions with

```
assumeThat(preconditionX, isSatisfied());
```

that throws `SkipException` when not satisfied. As a result I have 2 of 73 tests skipped while build in Jenkins is still green.

Skipped tests actually do not mean the build is broken but rather that environment or tests setup is wrong. But to me both things are important to be monitored. I cannot imagine to have a whole build green, if all tests are skipped.

Is there a way to mark a build as unstable if at least one test is skipped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Jenkins doesn't support this](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12567) because [`org.junit.Assume` is meant to be used as a filtering mechanism](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Assume.html).

[From the JUnit Assume docs](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Assume.html):

> A failed assumption does not mean the code is broken, but that the
>   test provides no useful information.

At first glance, this sounds like what you want. You want Jenkins to notify you about tests where the test environment has been set up "wrong," but you don't want it to count as a failure because the feature under test is not necessarily broken. **However, the feature under test is not necessarily working, either.**

That last part is critical. This is actually **not** what `org.junit.Assume` is meant for (by default.) It is not meant for indicating when the environment is bad, it is meant for skipping irrelevant data-points.

[From the JUnit Assume docs](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Assume.html):

> Failed assumptions **are usually not logged**, because there may be many
>   tests that don't apply to certain configurations.

[And also from the comments in that Jenkins bug I linked](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12567):

> Skipping is e.g. often used if certain tests cannot be run in the
>   current configuration (Unix specific tests when running on a Windows
>   platform).

Basically, Assume is supposed to be used to filter out tests that don't apply to certain configurations (like platform-specific tests.) The understanding is that the test gets run at some other time, when it is run against a valid (for that test) configuration. Meanwhile, you are trying to achieve some form of logging for bad configurations where you expect there is test/environment maintenance required.

You are trying to use it as an indicator for test/environment health, but it's really meant to be a filtering mechanism.

To be fair, your misuse of `Assume` is probably because `Assume` is a misleading name for the class. It should have been named something like `Filter` or `Exclude`.

To be double fair, JUnit basically doesn't have an mechanism to let you check which of your tests are valid, though at first glance it seems a lot like that is what `Assume` is meant for.

You will have to mark these cases as actual failures, either with a custom runner, or by just using [Assert](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Assert.html), like [this answer said](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/17914/41018).

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `assumeThat` in a method that creates a file whose presence indicates that at least one test was skipped.  Then add a build step that fails the build if that file is present.

You could replace the file with a row in a database or whatever.

Another option would be to replace `assumeThat` with something that throws an Error.  I believe the report generated by the junior test runner already distinguishes between failures and errors.

Answer (score 0):

org.junit.assume "is useful for stating assumptions about the conditions in which a test is meaningful". If a test isn't meanful (i.e. invalid given the circumstance) then it should be skipped.

Perhaps you want to look at [Assert](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Assert.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks but I still want to differiantate between tests that were run and failed and those that couldn't be run because of test environment misconfiguration.